# How do I check if function execution takes more than specified seconds?

Tags: java

I want to timeout the execution of a function if it takes more than 3 seconds.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
getStaticJsonResponse("build", "post");
long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = finishTime - startTime / 1000;
System.out.println("time" + elapsedTime);
```

Comment: you will have to use multithreading

Answer (score 10):

You need to have a separate thread which waits for the termination of the method or the timeout. Luckily, the creators of the great [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library have implemented this already: Just use a [TimeLimiter](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) (in your case, the [SimpleTimeLimiter](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html)).

Your code would look like this:

```
TimeLimiter limiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter();
String result = limiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() {
      return getStaticJsonResponse("build", "post");
    }
  }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, false);
```

(Assuming your method returns a String, otherwise adjust the return type).

Note that as with the other solutions, this guarantees that the caller will wait at most 3 seonds. It does however not guarantee that the method execution is actually aborted after 3 seconds. It is only aborted if the called code reacts to thread interrupts as done by `Thread.interrupt()`. All functions waiting for I/O do so, but your own code may not.

Comment: If you are using Spring, be carefull with request or session scope because you probably will lost the context, if change the scope you will get `java dispatcherservlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request`. Its seem this strategy does not work well with those scope

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the question right (since the other answers suggest otherwise), but I'm gathering that you want to implement a timeout on your `getStaticJsonResponse()` call (which I'm assuming is a blocking network call)?

If that is indeed the case, it is no simple task - implementing a timeout on top of a synchronous API is not necessarily easy.

One approach is to use a task thread. In this case, you would create a new class something like the following:

```
class JSONRequester implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        getStaticJsonResponse("build", "post");
    }
}
```

This basically just declares a class that can run your `getStaticJsonResponse()` on a separate thread. The original thread is then free to monitor the task thread and terminate it if it runs for too long.

To implement a timeout (of, say, 3 seconds), you could then do something like the following:

```
...

// Create and start the task thread.
Thread taskThread = new Thread(new JSONRequester ( ));
taskThread.start( );

// Wait 3 seconds.
sleep(3000);

// If after waiting 3 seconds the task is still running, stop it.
if (taskThread.isAlive( ))
    taskThread.interrupt( );

...
```

Here, the main thread starts the task thread, which in turn calls your `getStaticJsonResponse()` method. It then waits three seconds, and checks if the thread is still running. If the thread is running (i.e. `getStaticJsonResponse()` hasn't finished yet), it invokes the thread's `interrupt()` method, which causes an `InterruptedException` to be thrown in `JSONRequester`s `run()` method, thereby terminating the task thread.'

**EDIT:** I should note that this assumes a little bit about the code within `getStaticJsonResponse()`, particularly, that wherever the thread is blocking satisfies one of the conditions listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) for responding to the `interrupt()` call. However, in networking code (as this appears to be), this is usually a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: thanks for info,i am trying to implement this,i will just update here once done,this seems to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Timeout` class. Construct it with a parameter that represents the number of seconds you want. Give it a `HasTimedOut` member function. Periodically, in the function, call this member and if it returns `true`, return from the function.

Comment: can you suggest some links where i can look for this,as i a m not aware of doing multithreading

Comment: You most likely don't need multithreading to do what you want.

Comment: Can you brief out the timeout class

Comment: I pretty much did. It has a constructor that takes a number of seconds. On construction, it calculates the timeout time and stores it. It has a `HasTimedOut` member function that checks if the current time is past the timeout time. You just call `HasTimedOut` periodically in your code and if it returns `true`, your function aborts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle scenarios where a long running task may take longer than 3 seconds and it needs to be stopped if it does, you should perform your long running task in a separate thread. The simplest way to do this is to use Java's Executor framework.

Here's a basic example of running a potentially long (infinitely long) running task  in a thread and then timing it out when it has run for longer than three seconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.err.println("Start");

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(longRunningTask);
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.println("Time up - finished? " + executor.isTerminated()); //false
    executor.shutdownNow(); //runnable thread will be interrupted
}

private static Runnable longRunningTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // ... do some long running task

            //periodically check whether task should be aborted
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { //triggered by executor.shutdownNow() above
                break; //stop long running task
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Note that this will not be exactly 3 seconds (but close enough for a basic timeout), and that in a real world scenario the check for the interrupt should really check whether some (thread-safe, i.e. volatile) variable has been set as well, since an interrupt could have been triggered from another thread (but that's beyond the scope of this answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just change

```
long elapsedTime = finishTime - startTime / 1000;
```

to

```
long elapsedTime = (finishTime - startTime) / 1000;
```

and this should work.