# How to accept Junit 5 test after timeout?

Tags: java, junit5

When I place `@timeout` above the test then it fails when runs too long.

Hot to mark it as passed instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation of @timeout, @timeout is made to fail the test if the method doesn't meet to finish its operation within the required time. Hence, you cannot use @timeout to mark it as passed if the method is taking longer than it's expected.

Otherwise, based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374909/how-do-i-check-if-function-execution-takes-more-than-specified-seconds/9375313), to achieve your purpose, you can use Java Thread and sleep() method to check whether the Thread.isAlive() after some period of time.
Example:

```
...

// Create and start the task thread.
Thread taskThread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      System.out.println("Thread Running");
    }
  }
taskThread.start( );

// Wait 3 seconds.
sleep(3000);
boolean status = false;

// If after waiting 3 seconds the task is still running, stop it.
if (taskThread.isAlive( )) {
    taskThread.interrupt( );
} else {
    status = true;
}

assertTrue(status);
    

...
```